# Tripod center column locker screw lost

Tags: tripod, repair-parts

I have the following issue: I have a Vanguard Veo 235AB travel tripod and during a hike, I somehow lost the screw, which locks the center column. I love this tripod and it is perfectly usable, except for the fact that I cannot lock the column without this screw.
I have done a search, but I could not find any webshops, which would sell spareparts. Before I'm trying to have something hacked, I wanted to check with you all, if you have any ideas where to get the screw replaced.
Thanks in advance,
Viki

Comment: For me it seems like 1/4". So you can find some bolt to check and use it, something like can be helpful: https://www.amazon.com/4-28X1-Unslotted-Indented-Machine-Threaded/dp/B08XQWB85D

Comment: Have you tried contacting Vanguard? https://www.vanguardworld.com/pages/spare-parts

Comment: I wonder could you link to the exact model you have on the Vanguard website?

Comment: There are several different variations in the Veo 235AB line. Could you please tell us the exact model you have?